# File data not visible in textarea but can see it in console.log using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

Here I am trying to read the first file and trying to display it in the text area when I hit button RUN. When I use `getElementByID`, I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

But `getElementByID` works when I put text area in the same same `<div>` tag where the button `RUN` is present. But I am supposed to use the below format but I get error. I do not get any error with `getElementsByClassName` but I can just see the value in console.log but its not displayed in text area.

```js
    
       function loadFileAsText(){
     var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileUploader").files[0];
     var textFromFileLoaded;
     var fileReader = new FileReader();
     fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
       textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
       console.log(textFromFileLoaded);
       document.getElementsByClassName("classTextarea")[0].value = textFromFileLoaded;
          console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("classTextarea").value);
     };
     fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad);
       }
```

```html
        <div class="button files">
          <input id="fileUploader" type="file" multiple="multiple">
        </div>
        <div class="button run">
          <span type="button" onclick="loadFileAsText()">Run</span>
        </div>
    <article class="editor multiline">
      <div class="pad">
        <textarea id="idTextarea" class="classTextarea">
        </textarea>
      </div>
    </article>
```

Comment: `getElementAsID` --> shouldn't it supposed to be `getElementById`? Moreover an element with that ID should be available in DOM

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt corrected typo, Thank you. Yes I use `document.getElementById("idTextarea").value =  textFromFileLoaded;` but get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("classTextarea")` returns an array of elements, you need to choose the the first:

```js
function loadFileAsText() {
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileUploader").files[0];
    var textFromFileLoaded;
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
      textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
      console.log(textFromFileLoaded);
      document.getElementsByClassName("classTextarea")[0].value = textFromFileLoaded;
      console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("classTextarea")[0].value);
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad);
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 40px !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="button files">
    <input id="fileUploader" type="file" multiple="multiple">
  </div>
  <div class="button run">
    <span type="button" onclick="loadFileAsText()">Run</span>
  </div>
</div>
<article class="editor multiline">
  <div class="pad">
    <textarea id="idTextarea" class="classTextarea">
        </textarea>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when i change this in my code 
`document.getElementsByClassName("classTextarea")[0].value =  textFromFileLoaded;
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("classTextarea")[0].value);`
I get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined`

Is it becoz i am using <section> and <header>?

Comment: @JSCoder sorry I'm unable to reproduce your issue

Comment: @JSCoder and no I don;t think it is because of `section` and `header` tags, you might want to check your DOM once

Answer (score 0):

changing just `document.getElementsByClassName("classTextarea")` to `document.getElementsByClassName("classTextarea")[0]` works flawlessly. You only get the `undefined` error when you do not choose a file.

```js
    
       function loadFileAsText(){
     var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileUploader").files[0];
     var textFromFileLoaded;
     var fileReader = new FileReader();
     fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
       textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
       console.log(textFromFileLoaded);
       document.getElementsByClassName("classTextarea")[0].value = textFromFileLoaded;
          console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("classTextarea")[0].value);
     };
     fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad);
       }
```

```html
        <div class="button files">
          <input id="fileUploader" type="file" multiple="multiple">
        </div>
        <div class="button run">
          <span type="button" onclick="loadFileAsText()">Run</span>
        </div>
    <article class="editor multiline">
      <div class="pad">
        <textarea id="idTextarea" class="classTextarea">
        </textarea>
      </div>
    </article>
```